# Advice on android setlistadapter and combining two .xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listadapter

I am using two list adapter as shown on code below. resultList and resultList2 are initialized with `new ArrayList <HashMap<String,String>>();`

```
ListAdapter adapter, adapter2;
adapter =new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), resultList, 
                R.layout.list_item1, new String[]{TAG_ID, TAG_FRUIT, TAG_SPECIES},
                new int[]{R.id.Id,R.id.fruit,R.id.species});
adapter2=new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), resultList2, 
                R.layout.list_item_append, new String[]{ TAG_NAME, TAG_ADDRESS, TAG_EMAIL},
                new int[]{ R.id.name, R.id.address, R.id.email});
setListAdapter(adapter);
setListAdapter(adapter2);    //this line has overriden setListAdapter(adapter)
```

I have two layouts named list_item1.xml and list_item2.xml.

```
//list_item.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:visibility="gone"/><!--android:visibility="gone"  --> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fruit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/species"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

second layout: list_item2.xml
        list_item.xml

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I have tried to use `<include>` and `<merge>` in my new layout but it is not the result I wanted. The result shows all the elements in adapter2. But there are empty list element before each of the adapter2 elements.
My expected result are:
adapter....
adapter....
adapter...
adapter2...
adapter2...
adapter2...
How can I achieve this? I think that setListAdapter is the cause of the problem.

The reason i used two listadapter is because i am trying two fetch two set of data from my database. The data is fetch from the table named tblfruit and tblperson.

```
    $response["results"] = array();
    $response["results2"] = array();
    // temp user array
    $results = array();
    $results2=array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $results["id"] = $row["id"];
        $results["fruit"] = $row["fruit"];
        $results["species"] = $row["species"];
        array_push($response["results"], $results);
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
        $results2["name"] = $row["name"];
        $results2["address"] = $row["address"];
        $results2["email"] = $row["email"];
        array_push($response["results2"], $results2);
    }
```

Comment: Use two different ListView for two different adapter.

Comment: Use the same listview (just one listview) with just one adapter, and inside the adapter use type of items and call the layout you need for each item

Comment: hi, dhaval and hi bmarqes. I have editted my question. Please have a look thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - ListView Adapter with items of two views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728238/android-listview-adapter-with-items-of-two-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend `ListAdapter` and inflate each row with your desired layout within the Adapter's [`View.getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method. This method is called once for each row in the ListView (or record inside the adapter, if you want to be specific). It is used to set up (or, well, inflate) the view for each record, and doing things such as setting the value of `TextView`'s, `ImageView`'s, hiding unnecessary components for each row, etc. I haven't tried this with two differente layout resources myself, but I suppose it can be done with this approach.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomObject> {

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId_1;
    private int layoutResourceId_2
    private List<CustomObject> list;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId_1, int layoutResourceId_2, List<CustomObject> list) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId_1, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId_1 = layoutResourceId_1;
        this.layoutResourceId_2 = layoutResourceId_2;
        this.list = list;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

        if(condition_layout_1()) {
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId_1, parent, false);
            // Use a holder to prepare item
            ...
        } else {
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId_2, parent, false);
            // Use a holder to prepare item
            ...
        }

        return row;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: hi, cramps. I used the same concept as the mentioned solution. It's work! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to merge list_item1 and resultList2 layouts for whatever you are trying to achieve.Instead of extending ListActivity or ListFragment, use ordinary activity and setContentView with a layout that has two listviews in its xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

and then in your java file

```
    ListView listview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ListView listview2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    listview1.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview2.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

I am not sure if this meets your requirement.Sorry if it doesn't.I hope it helps.

Comment: hi, dora. thanks for your reply and I'm really appreciate it. =) I tried to used this approach but it's not the result i wanted. Thanks again.